# Dock is not working

Tags: asp.net, telerik

**if i will change SlideDirection to right then it will not work shows blank and no dick pin there but for Left property it works**

```
 <center>
      <telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter1" runat="server" Height="300" Width="500">

          <telerik:RadPane ID="EndPane" runat="server" Width="220" Scrolling="None">
               <telerik:RadSlidingZone ID="RadSlidingZone1" runat="server" Width="22" ClickToOpen="false"            SlideDirection="Left">
                    <telerik:RadSlidingPane ID="RadSlidingPane2" Title="Pane1" runat="server" Width="150"
                         MinWidth="130">
                         1
                    </telerik:RadSlidingPane>

               </telerik:RadSlidingZone>
          </telerik:RadPane>
     </telerik:RadSplitter>
     </center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the size of the pane that may help